# GroovyRuntimeException: Cannot read write-only property

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, groovy, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-java-2.0

With this snippet,

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsBasicCredentials
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.DynamoDbClient

DynamoDbClient dynamoDB = DynamoDbClient.builder()
    .region(Region.US_EAST_1)
    .credentialsProvider(AwsBasicCredentials.create(KEY, SECRET_KEY))
    .build()
```

I receive a rather cryptic error message:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Cannot read write-only property: credentialsProvider
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Cannot read write-only property: credentialsProvider
```

Any hints on what I should be looking for?

Comment: That's an odd error message, but I'm pretty sure the root cause is that you need to be wrapping your ABC in a `StaticCredentialsProvider`. (Using `@CompileStatic` can also help with this.)

Comment: Just figured the same thing out. That error had me on a wild goose chase for some time. Can you point me to more information about `@CompileStatic` please?

Comment: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/CompileStatic.html

Comment: what are the versions of groovy and java? could you try to put `.` at the end of previous line instead of beginning of new line. to use `@CompileStatic` - create a function like `getDynamoClient(){...}` and add `@groovy.transform.CompileStatic` annotation for it.

Comment: the problem that method [`credentialsProvider`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/2.0.0-preview-11/software/amazon/awssdk/awscore/client/builder/AwsClientBuilder.html#credentialsProvider-software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsCredentialsProvider-) expects [`AwsCredentialsProvider`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/2.0.0-preview-11/software/amazon/awssdk/auth/credentials/AwsCredentialsProvider.html) and you are providing [`AwsBasicCredentials`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/2.0.0-preview-11/software/amazon/awssdk/auth/credentials/AwsBasicCredentials.html)